# Drupal module version in Admin does not match .info file

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, wysiwyg

I'm installing an updated WYSIWYG module - the latest DEV build: https://www.drupal.org/project/wysiwyg

After installing the module the version number of the module shown in the administration page doesn't match the version in the .info file on the file system. I've flushed all caches and run update. The admin page should be showing the same version number as the .info file:

Admin page

[image]

.info file:

> version = "7.x-2.2+54-dev"

On another website we're managing which uses this new WYSIWYG module the versions match.

Answer (score 1):

I had a backup of the old module in `sites/all/modules/wysiwyg.original` - Drupal was picking up the old one.